# Is it possible to simulate touchevent on YUI 3.6.0?

Tags: touch, yui, simulation

In older versions of YUI, it's not possible to simulate touchevent (touchstart/touchmove/touchend), as we can read on the official yui website : http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/event/simulate.html (No touch event section)

But in the last version of YUI (3.6.0) it appears that is possible to simulate touchevent. When you look at this file : http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/files/event-simulate_js_event-simulate.js.html#l60, touchevents are implemented in the script.

And if you look at this post : http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2012/08/10/twiy/; YUI accept a pull request about gesture simulation.

But when I do this :

```
 Y.one('mydiv').simulate('touchstart');
```

i have this message :

```
 Error: simulate(): Event 'touchstart' can't be simulated. Use gesture-simulate module instead.
```

So i try to used "gesturemovestart" and do

```
 Y.one('mydiv').simulate('gesturemovestart');
```

but i have this message :

```
Event 'gesturemovestart' can't be simulated
```

So, is anyone know if it's definitively possible to simulate touchevent on YUI, and if yes, why do I have this error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you refer to the event-simulate.js from yui3 on git hub
https://github.com/yui/yui3/blob/master/build/event-simulate/event-simulate.js, line 725 of the comment says touchevents expect param touchList[A collection of Touch objects representing all touches associated with this event].
So if you try something similar to 
Y.one("#myDiv").simulate("touchstart", { touches: {PageX: 200, PageY: 200} });

it should simulate touchstart event.

And as touch and gesture events are Available on iOS (2.0 and later), the test should pass successfully on ios devices.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found answers.

You can do Y.one("#myDiv").simulate("touchstart", { touches: {PageX: 0, PageY: 0} }); but only for Android & iOs system, which is ok for my script (running on tablet & smartphone).

You have to update to YUI 3.6.0. , if you want to use it.

If you refer to this post : http://yuilibrary.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=10521, gesture simulation will be implemented in YUI next version 3.6.1.